# Pandas replace column values with rolling sum of that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Although this question may seem like a duplicate of many others, I haven't been able to find a solution that doesn't require creating a new column within my dataframe or dropping a column and appending a new one on to the end.

Suppose I have the following:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_name, encoding='utf-8')
new_dataframe = dataframe[['Date Time', 'T (degC)', 'rh (%)', 'Tdew (degC)', 'rain (mm)', 'p (mbar)', 'wv (m/s)']]
```

This gives me a pandas DataFrame with 7 columns and a large number of rows, for the sake of simplicity, I'll be using the `.head()` function to have a clearer display.

What I would like to do is a rolling sum along the `rain (mm)` column and replace the values in said column by the calculated rolling sum. The data I have is every 10 minutes and I want a sum over the last 3 hours so I'm applying the following to my variable `new_dataframe`:

`print(new_dataframe.loc[:, ['rain (mm)']].rolling(18).sum().round(2).head(20))` which gives me the following output:

```
    rain (mm)
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
5         NaN
6         NaN
7         NaN
8         NaN
9         NaN
10        NaN
11        NaN
12        NaN
13        NaN
14        NaN
15        NaN
16        NaN
17        0.0
18        0.0
19        0.0
```

The `NaN` isn't an issue since I have other variables in my dataframe which will cause me to remove many entries including those ones.

Printing the global `new_dataframe` variable gives this output:

```
              Date Time  T (degC)  rh (%)  Tdew (degC)  rain (mm)  p (mbar)  wv (m/s)
0   01.07.2002 00:10:04     15.44   66.01         9.13        0.0    995.50   -9999.0
1   01.07.2002 00:20:04     15.42   66.91         9.31        0.0    995.44   -9999.0
2   01.07.2002 00:30:04     15.29   67.51         9.32        0.0    995.34   -9999.0
3   01.07.2002 00:40:04     15.15   69.59         9.64        0.0    995.27   -9999.0
4   01.07.2002 00:50:04     14.80   75.20        10.46        0.0    995.19   -9999.0
5   01.07.2002 01:00:04     14.38   77.90        10.58        0.0    995.11   -9999.0
6   01.07.2002 01:10:04     14.12   80.10        10.75        0.0    995.06   -9999.0
7   01.07.2002 01:20:04     13.91   81.90        10.88        0.0    995.05   -9999.0
8   01.07.2002 01:30:04     13.75   81.60        10.66        0.0    995.06   -9999.0
9   01.07.2002 01:40:04     13.74   81.90        10.71        0.0    995.05   -9999.0
10  01.07.2002 01:50:04     13.69   82.10        10.70        0.0    995.03   -9999.0
11  01.07.2002 02:00:04     13.50   82.70        10.62        0.0    994.99   -9999.0
12  01.07.2002 02:10:04     13.32   85.20        10.89        0.0    994.93   -9999.0
13  01.07.2002 02:20:04     13.17   85.40        10.78        0.0    994.86   -9999.0
14  01.07.2002 02:30:04     13.08   84.10        10.46        0.0    994.80   -9999.0
15  01.07.2002 02:40:04     12.96   85.70        10.63        0.0    994.80   -9999.0
16  01.07.2002 02:50:04     12.92   87.90        10.97        0.0    994.81   -9999.0
17  01.07.2002 03:00:04     12.89   87.60        10.89        0.0    994.81   -9999.0
18  01.07.2002 03:10:04     12.94   87.60        10.94        0.0    994.76   -9999.0
19  01.07.2002 03:20:04     12.80   85.70        10.47        0.0    994.73   -9999.0
```

(For those wondering, yes the `-9999.0` is what I will be using to remove unnecessary rows)

What I would like to do is simply replace the `rain (mm)` column in `new_dataframe` with the one in calculating the rolling sum. I insist on the word **REPLACE** since I need the column to stay at the same index.

Thanks in advance!

If this is somehow a duplicate, please let me know. I'll follow up by confirming if the proposed duplicate actually solves my issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

Having spent some time fiddling around, I found the following solution:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_name, encoding='utf-8')
new_dataframe = dataframe[['Date Time', 'T (degC)', 'rh (%)', 'Tdew (degC)', 'rain (mm)', 'p (mbar)', 'wv (m/s)']].copy()
temp_dataframe = dataframe.loc[:, ['rain (mm)']].rolling(18).sum().round(2)
new_dataframe['rain (mm)'] = temp_dataframe['rain (mm)']
print(new_dataframe.head(20))
```

The addition of the `.copy()` when creating the `new_dataframe` variable solves the `SettingWithCopyWarning` and gives the expected result.

The warning was caused by the fact my initial code was in fact directly modifying the dataframe read from the csv file which often led to warnings or errors.